# Convert matrix from character to factor

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a basic matrix from one type to another. This seems like a really basic question, but surprisingly I have not seen an answer to it.

Here's a simple example:

```
> btest <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9], ncol = 3)
> ctest <- apply(btest, 2, as.factor)
> class(ctest[1,1])
[1] "character"
```

The only examples I could find on stack overflow dealt with data.frame columns, which seems more straightforward...

```
dtest <- as.data.frame(btest, stringsAsFactors = F)
dtest[] <- lapply(dtest[colnames(dtest)], as.factor)
dtest
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  D  G
2  B  E  H
3  C  F  I
class(dtest[1,1])
[1] "factor"
```

Is there a straightforward way to change a matrix from character to factor and specify the levels as well?

Comment: matrix holds only one data type. Factor is a complex data type made up of character and integer types. Matrix cannot hold two types at a time. List is the appropriate data structure for factor. Data.frame is a kind of list data structure.

Comment: So essentially you can't have a matrix that is factors?

Comment: You could reconstruct one with `structure(factor(btest), dim = dim(btest), class = c('matrix', 'factor'))`, but I'm not confident that won't cause terrible problems.

Comment: If someone puts this as an answer I can accept it, this clears up my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matrix holds only one data type. Factor is a complex data type made up of character and integer types. Matrix cannot hold two types at a time. List is the appropriate data structure for factor. Data.frame is a kind of list data structure.

The help documentation of matrix `?matrix` states that

> an optional data vector (including a list or expression
>   vector). Non-atomic classed R objects are coerced by as.vector and all
>   attributes discarded.

The attributes for a factor is shown below.

```
attributes(factor(letters[1:4]))
$levels
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

$class
[1] "factor"
```

These attributes are removed using `as.vector` during matrix formation.

```
attributes(as.vector(factor(letters[1:4])))
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, a matrix is mostly just a vector with a `dim` attribute of length 2 (see `?matrix`). Its class is `matrix`, but it usually isn't stored as an attribute, unlike with list-based objects.

Thus, you can reconstruct a factor matrix with `structure`:

```r
btest <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9], ncol = 3)

btest_fac <- structure(factor(btest), dim = dim(btest), class = c('matrix', 'factor'))

btest_fac
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] A    D    G   
#> [2,] B    E    H   
#> [3,] C    F    I   
#> Levels: A B C D E F G H I

str(btest_fac)
#>  matrix [1:3, 1:3] A B C D ...
#>  - attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:9] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

class(btest_fac)
#> [1] "matrix" "factor"
```

However, while this is *possible*, it's not very useful, as functions will deal with it unpredictably, e.g. `apply` will coerce it to integer. You could define your own class and appropriate methods for it, but that would be a lot more work.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I always heard that matrices are just vectors with a dim attribute of length 2, so I thought that meant they could likewise handle any vector type (eg factors, characters, etc).

Comment: They can, but factors aren't a type, they're integers with a class and an attribute for the levels. Unfortunately, attributes in R are occasionally dropped without warning. At the end of the day, the easiest way to deal with this situation is probably to use a matrix of integers corresponding to the levels (e.g. `btest[] <- factor(btest)`), do whatever you like to it, and the map the levels back in at the end. Or just use a character matrix.